# How can i send the test result file by email in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to send the test result file via email after the test has been completed in jmeter by automatically. If anyone have some idea pls let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Thread Group to the Test Plan.

Add an HTTP Sampler and set up the required parameters, like Server Name, Method, Path, etc.

[image: Screenshot-1]

Add the "Summary Report" listener to the Thread Group. Configure the File Name parameter to define the file where reports will be saved (the default file path is JMeter's bin directory). The File Name parameter is important as it will be referenced by the SMTP sampler.

[image: Screenshot-2]

Add a tearDown Thread group to the Test Plan. The tearDown thread group will run only after the test has been execute, so it will run after the first Thread Group is completed.

Add the SMTP Sampler to the Tear-Down Thread group and configure the mail server parameters. A demo configuration using Gmail. The SMTP server would use the following parameter values:

- Server- smtp.googlemail.com
- Port- 587
- Address From - sender@gmail.com
- Address To - recipient@gmal.com
- Auth Settings

  - username - sender@gmail.com
  - password - sender's Gmail password
- Security Settings - Use StartTLS
- Message Settings -

  - Subject - Email Subject/Title to be used
  - Message - Email body goes here
  - Attach File(s) - enter the filename used in the Summary Report Listener in Step 3

When using Gmail as an SMTP server, you might need to configure Gmail's settings to allow "Less-Secured" apps to sign in; otherwise, Google may block JMeter from sending any emails.

[image: Screenshot-3]

[image: Screenshot-4]

Now, restart the JMeter and run the test again. You should be able to get the test report on mail with complete data.

Comment: Kindly upvote and accept the answer if it works fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to the TestPlan.

   > A special type of ThreadGroup that can be utilized to perform Post-Test Actions. The behavior of these threads is exactly like a normal Thread Group element. The difference is that these type of threads execute after the test has finished executing its regular Thread Groups.
2. Add [SMTP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) to the tearDown Thread Group
3. Set up SMTP Sampler email settings, such as host, port, user, password, etc of your email server.
4. SMTP Sampler - Attach File — choose file report what you want to attach after test stop.

Answer (score 0):

1. user jp@gc flexible file writer (or any file writer) to store the API result in the file
2. add SMTP Sampler in teardown thread group (i have attached image)
   [image]

3. once the test is completed, the teardown thread group will be executed and a test result email will be sent.